# Is there a special user and group for a shared file which anyone can read/write in linux?

Tags: linux

I am making a folder where there are some shared files which can be read and written by anyone (but not executable) in a server. But I don't know what kind of owner and group are used for the files. Are there any special or well known owner or group for the purpose? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to     http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since it is on a server, did you consider using some version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/). You should motivate your question, and generally having such a directory (Linux does not have folders, except on the screens, but directories) is a bad idea. BTW, your question is off-topic here. Remember that several processes could on Linux write the same file (or directory) concurrently, and you might not want that to be easy.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to do this would be to use:

```
 chmod 110
```

This will change file permission to read & write, no execute

linuxcommand.org/lts0070